# Tokenizing Result of XPath Selection

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XPath Expression:

```
//gym/person/clientMembers/member[@membershipID='60410001']/name/text()
```

Which selects the data value: 
          Charles McKlarkey

From XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gym>
    <person>
        <clientMembers>
        <member membershipID ="60410001">
                <name> Charles McKlarkey</name>
                <contactNo> 02147483647 </contactNo>
                <email> CharlesM@gmail.com </email>
                <date-of-birth> 1986-02-20</date-of-birth>
                <sex> Male </sex>
                <expiryDate> 2017-02-22 </expiryDate>
                <owns membershipType="Platinum"/>
        </member>
  </person>
</gym>
```

And wish to Tokenize the result so that the final query will return "Charles" "McKlarkey".

I have done some messing around with the Tokenize Function but cannot seem to get one that works for this. Would anyone be able to assist?

I am using: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath to test my expressions.

Comment: this is because http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath uses XPath 1.0, which doesn't implement tokenize. Sadly, there isn't a split/tokenize method for XPath 1.0

Comment: They have support for XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0 - at least when I am looking at it? I have also used to for Aggregate functions which I believe are also XPath 2.0 specific.

Comment: ok, so it should work eventually then

Comment: Yeah, I just can't seem to find a way to make the Tokenize expression perform on the evaluated expression of `//gym/person/clientMembers/member[@membershipID='60410001']/name/text()` instead of the literal string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the tools you're using. It is only able to return single string result. Given your current XML (assuming `clientMembers` element was properly closed), the output of the following XPath there will be an *empty string* since there is a space before 'Charles' in the XML :

```
//gym/person/clientMembers/member[@membershipID='60410001']/name/tokenize(., ' ')
```

**<kbd>[`test 1`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/0da26660fbb528468f619ca044d5e7b8)</kbd>**

When you remove that single space form the input XML, the result will be *just 'Charles'* :

**<kbd>[`test 2`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/bfde7c13a915240cf50e4697eb1b62dd)</kbd>**

Using [another tool](http://xpatheval.apphb.com), for example, the result of the same XPath is as expected :

```
Charles
McKlarkey
```

**<kbd>[`test 3`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/3LYh2Rz_5)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you!

I had to use XPathTester.com as that is what my lecturer enforced and it was driving me mad working out why it wasn't evaluating correctly despite my absolute best efforts.